# Electric field in a circuit static vs induced

Tags: electric-fields

I am on a quest to learn Maxwell's equations and feel I have made a lot of progress in understanding of them. But there is one thing that is bothering me. In a static electric circuit, the electric field is perpendicular to the conductor and current flow. But in an induced field caused by a changing magnetic field, the electric field is circular  and seems to be tangential to a circuit loop and current flow. This creates a conflict for me because in one case the electric field is perpendicular and the other case it is tangential but the current flow in the circuit is the same. Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: if it is static then there is no current flowing, the current flows only if there is an electric field along the wire, like when you have a battery,

Comment: By static I meant no changing electric field, which would be the case with a battery

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/226266/why-is-there-an-electric-field-in-a-wire-even-though-it-is-a-conductor