# How is electric current possible if no electric field exists inside a conductor?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, conductors

> How is electric current possible if no electric field exists inside a conductor?

Since no electric field exists inside a conductor. How is electric current possible as $$v_d=\frac{(eE)t}{2m},\;\;{E=0}$$ and $$i=neAv_d$$So current should be zero. Why is it not so?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/226266/why-is-there-an-electric-field-in-a-wire-even-though-it-is-a-conductor/226269#226269

Answer (score 0):

E=0 in a conductor under static conditions (no movement of charges) because charges are free to move so if there were an E field charges would be moving. The case of a current is different - charges are moving so E is nonzero.